# Получить данные из таблицы java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

у меня имеется таблица jtable, из которой мне нужно сохранить значения столбца. подскажите как я мог бы это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так можно прочитать их в ArrayList, a дальше сохаранить уж куда вам надо:

```
        JTable table; //Ваша таблица
        final int COLUMN = 1; //Номер сталбца
        ArrayList<Object> column = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
            column.add(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, COLUMN));
        }
```